# Calculate area of adjoining raster class cells inside polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, shapefile, area, tabulate

I am calculating the size of deforestation in private properties. My two data sets are a raster layer of deforested patches, each containing a number as the year it has been deforested, and a polygon layer of the region for the properties. 
Using Tabulate Area I have the total area deforested each year on each property. 
I would like now to analyse the size of the polygons deforested, ie. , calculate area of raster cells of same value that are adjoining on each property.

Is there a way to accomplish this on ArcGIS?

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close at the moment.  The tools you can use are in the same toolbox as the Tabulate Area tool.  Have a look at **[Zonal Geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-geometry.htm)**.  It can calculate the area for each zone.

**[Zonal Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics.htm)** might also be useful depending on your particular datasets.

Alternatively, you could convert your rasters to polygons and perform a union or interesection. Then, you can just perform area calculations on the results and summarise.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at those. I'd rather work with rasters because my dataset is huge and it is just so much faster using rasters.

Comment: I've looked at those, but they put they define "A zone is defined as all areas in the input that have the same value. The areas do not have to be contiguous".  So wouldn't this do the same that I've already done?